# jQuery Select form field with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to create the jquery select field which includes images. (http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick)

It seems that there is something wrong with my code, as the console is showing an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ddslick'

HTML

```
<form id="quote" action="" method="get"><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$('#quote').keyup(function (){   doTotal(this);   calcMenu(this); ddslick(this); });
// ]]></script>

<table id="table1" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Enquiry Date</td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="dateToday" size="25" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Conference Name</td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="conferenceName" size="25" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company Name</td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="companyName" size="25" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Special Requests</td>
<td><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="26"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="table2" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="firstName" size="25" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="lastName" size="25" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tel No</td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="telNo" size="25" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cell</td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="cellNo" size="25" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="email" size="25" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input onclick="formReset()" type="button" value="Reset form" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="tablex" border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="col" width="30">
<div align="center">Date</div></th>
<th scope="col" width="128">
<div align="center">Amount of Delegates ½ Day Conference @ R 240 pp</div></th>
<th width="112">
<div align="center">Amount of Delegates Full Day Conference @ R 260 pp</div></th>
<th width="112">
<div align="center">Menu No</div></th>
<th width="112">
<div align="center">Price pp for Menu (1-7: R70, 8-10 R85, 11: R105, 12: R85)</div></th>
<th width="112">
<div align="center">Total Persons for meals</div></th>
<th width="112">
<div align="center">Amount of Single Rooms @ R 480 pp</div></th>
<th width="112">
<div align="center">Amount of Double Rooms @ R 720 pp</div></th>
<th width="134">
<div align="center">Total for the day</div></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="date1" size="10" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="halfday1" size="5" maxlength="10" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="fullday1" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="MenuNo1" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="MenuPrice1" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="MealPersons1" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="SingleRooms1" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="DoubleRooms1" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="total1" size="5" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="date2" size="10" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="halfday2" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="fullday2" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="MenuNo2" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="MenuPrice2" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="MealPersons2" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="SingleRooms2" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="DoubleRooms2" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="total2" size="5" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="date3" size="10" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="halfday3" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="fullday3" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="MenuNo3" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="MenuPrice3" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="MealPersons3" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="SingleRooms3" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="DoubleRooms3" size="5" /></div></td>
<td>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="total3" size="5" /></div></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div id="myDropdown">
<select id="myDropdown">
        <option value="0" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Facebook">Facebook</option>
        <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Twitter">Twitter</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with LinkedIn">LinkedIn</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Foursquare">Foursquare</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>


$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
    }   
});
```

Comment: have you included the plugin's script file

Comment: you don't need to call `ddslick(this);`

Comment: Shouldn't be the jQuery code at the bottom be wrapped with `<script>` tags?

Comment: @ArunPJohny  Yes in header.php.  `jquery.ddslick.js`

Comment: @ArnelleBalane  I'm using a wordpress plugin that includes the script tags

Comment: I have tried my code in a jsfiddle, and it is not working either?http://jsfiddle.net/newbie123/zUgyd/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress, try following this steps:

1 - Copy the jquery.ddslick.js file in the /js folder of your theme.

2 - Be sure you have write the correct path to the file in your header.php. Inside the `<head>` tag you should have something like this:

```
<script src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.ddslick.js'></script>
```

3 - As @Arnelle Balane has point out, you probably should write this piece of code:

```
$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
    }   
});
```

Inside some script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
    }   
});
</script>
```

Or, you can put that code inside your custom .js file. That way you don't have to put all the code in the html:

a - Inside your /js folder, make another .js file, something like this: script.js

b - Inside the script.js file, copy the above code without script tags inside a jQuery on ready function, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myDropdown').ddslick({
        onSelected: function(selectedData){
            //callback function: do something with selectedData;
        }   
    });
});
```

4 - Check you have jquery activate on your theme, if not, you can download jquery from [here](http://jquery.com/download/) and repeat step 2 for the jQuery file or you can use [jQuery from wordpress](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/).

5 - Double check for typos and test if works; if not, is probably something else; keep us informed.

Update: I add more info in the step three, in case of using a external .js file.

Comment: thank you very much.  I have included the .js and made the necessary changes and it's working in the fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/zUgyd/7/  but not in wordpress?

Comment: Mmm, try using  a external .js file for the code in the step 3 (without the script tags). Are you using jQuery from wordpress?.